# CodeIgniter Pagination - How to change the base url on page 1?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

My base url is: $config['base_url'] = base_url()."students/page";

*For example:*

Landing page url is: /domain-name/students

```
Previous  1 **2** 3 4 Next ›
```

If I go to page 2 the url changes to: /domain-name/students/page/2 - This is correct, I have defined this $config['base_url'] = base_url()."students/page

but, when I go back to page 1 - I would like the url to change back to my landing url: domain-name/students. Currenlty it's going to domain-name/students/page/

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to specify the `first_url` parameter in your pagination config, so do this in your controller:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
 //.....etc
 $pagination['first_url'] = site_url('students/page');
//....etc
$this->pagination->initialize($pagination);
```

then for **previous** link you can do:

```
$pagination['prev_link']  = '<a href="'.site_url('students/page').'">previous</a>';
```

try i don't tryed this, it should work

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks. Now, the only problem is with previous link.

Is there a way to set the same link like first_url for previous link?

Comment: @sappy i think i didn't catched at all, do you want always the previous link to point to unique url/first_url? do you know **$this->pagination** it's an object and you can use it as you want? try **var_dump($this->pagination);** in your view and you will see all that pagination object contains ;)

Comment: @sapppy  i think i didn't catched at all, do you want always the previous link to point to unique url/first_url? do you know $this->pagination it's an object and you can use it as you want? try var_dump($this->pagination); in your view and you will see all that pagination object contains ;)

Comment: Hi okok, sorry its my fault I didn\'t explained.
<br/><br/>
Basically, lets assume I am on page 2, example: domain-name/students/page/2 and my pagination looks like *"< Previous 1 **2** 3 4 Next >"* - In your previous comments my link 1 is working perfect **domain-name/students**. But problem is, while on page 2 there is a **< previous** link, when I click on this it goes to domain-name/students/page which is wrong, instead it should go to domain-name/students same like when I click on link 1 of pagination.<br/><br/> Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi, the above **['pref_link']** you mentioned works fine from page no. 2 - **previous link**. But, when I am on **page no. 3** and I click  **previous link**  this takes me to the **domain-name/students** instead of **domain-name/students/page/2**

Comment: error correction from my previous comment - It's ['prev_link'] not ['pref_link']

Comment: Found the solution - is this the correct way of doing this?  
    **if($this->uri->segment(3) == '2')  
    {  
    $config['prev_link'] = '<a href="'.site_url('domain-name/students').'">&#8249; Previous</a>';  
    }  
    else  
    {  
    $config['prev_link'] = '&#8249; Previous';  
    }**

Comment: @sapppy no problems, enjoy CI ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by sbaaaang is not correct.

`$config['prev_link']` is meant for the text that will be displayed for the previous link: "Previous", "Prev", "<" , "<-", ... anything you want. It will be rendered within  tags.

If you set `$config['prev_link']` to `'<a href="'.site_url('students/page').'">previous</a>';`, you get the following: `<a href=".../1"><a href="...">previous</a></a>`, two `<a>` tags with one having the wrong url.

I don't know what the solution to the original question is though, and I'm struggling with the same issue. I think it's something with the Pagination library, as I explained here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/240326/